# Add custom field to Fiori App "Record Defect" (F2929) - SAP Quality Management

Tags: abap, sap-fiori, cds

I tried to add a custom field (simple CHAR20 text) to the Fiori App "Record Defect" (F2929), but I got really stuck.

What I have tried:

I followed this blogpost (https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/01/adding-field-in-standard-fiori-apps-of-s-4hana-with-custom-fields-and-logic/) for adding the custom field via Fiori App Custom Fields & Logic. Here I added the custom text field to the Business Context "Notification Item / Defect". I noticed, that the table QMFE was appended and I was able to see the newly created custom field in the filter section of the Fiori App "Manage Defects". But still, the field is not visible in the header section of "Create Defect"...

So I followed another blogpost (https://blogs.sap.com/2022/08/05/__trashed-86/) for adding a custom field via SAP transaction SCFD_EUI. I published it and I was able to see the field in the Custom Field & Logic App. Here I enabled it for all suggested apps but still no success.

After reading a ton of several blogpost I found this step by step guide (https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/2bc3ee8d1c83404e8cf62418640004f2/253ec4c8d01f44a0b256615bf3d581c1.html) to add the field to the consumer view C_DefectRecord by a SAP Metadata Extension. I have created the extension, activated it, cleared the metadata cache of the OData service and still can't see the field in the app...

What can I do or check to find a missing configuration?